Getting System.Xml.XmlException error when executing sematic kernel sk.InvokeAsync method when having some special characters
I have this semantic kernel .yaml hadlebar template and I want to insert transcript text below into it at runtime to get a structured response in JSON format using GetSpeakerNames method (c#.net core)
I am getting a parsing error in Microsoft.SemanticKernel's XmlPromptParser class's TryParse method when trying to load the template along with transcription text.
xmlDocument.LoadXml($"{prompt}");
System.Xml.XmlException: 'Name cannot begin with the '1' character, hexadecimal value 0x31. Line 7, position 26.'
I tried escaping content of ... at run time as well inserted escaped characters in handlebars template as well. Nothing helps.
Transcription.SpeakerId.yaml


name: TranscriptionSpeakers
description: Takes a conversation dialog transcripts and identifies the speakers
template: |
  <message role="system"> Your  input is a speaker based transcription of a conversation between two or more people. In the transcription, the speakers will only be known as SPEAKER 1, SPEAKER 2, etc. 
  Your goal it to identify the names of the speakers if possible.

  Return your results in a JSON format

  {
   "SPEAKER 1" : "<speaker 1 name>",
   "SPEAKER 2" : "<speaker 2 name>",
   "SPEAKER 3" : "<speaker 3 name>"
  }

  If you can not positively identify a speaker from the transcription, leave the value as the current speaker placeholder, e.g. "SPEAKER 1" instead of adding somethng else such as "UNKNOWN". In this scenario, the output would be:

  {
   "SPEAKER 1" : "<speaker 1 name>",
   "SPEAKER 2" : "SPEAKER 2",
   "SPEAKER 3" : "SPEAKER 3"
  }

  IMPORTANT: Do not include any other text in your response other than the JSON object. If you do, your response will be rejected.

  </message>
  <message role="user">{{transcription}}</message>
  <message role="system">JSON formatted response</message>
template_format: handlebars
input_variables: 
 - name: transcription
   description: Text of the transcribed conversation
   is_required: true
execution_settings:
  default: 
    max_tokens: 4096
    temperature: 0.0
   



transcript text:


SPEAKER 1: Hi, my name is David Johnson. My laptop keeps disconnecting from Wi-Fi. It's very frustrating.
SPEAKER 2: It is Alex Matrix here. I'm sorry to hear that. Let's see if we can get this resolved. Have you tried connecting to different networks to see if the issue persists?
SPEAKER 1: I hope it gets resolved soon. This issue is really affecting my work.
SPEAKER 2: We understand how important it is to have a reliable Wi-Fi connection. We'll do our best to resolve this quickly. Is there anything else I can help you with today?
SPEAKER 1: No, that's all. Thanks.
SPEAKER 3: You're welcome. Have a nice day.



Code:


internal async Task<Dictionary<string, string>?> GetSpeakerNames(string sourceFileName, string transcription)
{
 Dictionary<string, string> speakerDict = null;
 try
 
    var result = await sk.InvokeAsync(yamlPrompts["Transcription_SpeakerId"], new() { { "transcription", transcription } });
    try
    {
       speakerDict = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(result.GetValue<string>());
       return speakerDict;
    }
    catch (Exception exe)
    {
       log.LogError($"Error getting speaker names: {exe.Message}");
       return speakerDict;
    }
 }
}




Pure guessing: Your template is invalid XML: "<speaker 1 name>" means: Tag speaker with attributes 1 and name but "1" is not a valid xml attribute name because attributes must start with a character or underscore.
